# Coprocessor Synchronization

Tags: bus, sharedbus

I have a coprocessor that uses some dedicated hardware 65c618 core that starts up in a halted state. Through a dedicated bus I can control the coprocessor I-RAM which is needed to setup the processor state and transfer the program into its onboard SRAM.

I plan on using a 72Mhz STM32F103RB to handle the coprocessor interface but am unsure how to synchronize the common shared bus properly. I know the cycle time of all opcodes and I can drive the coprocessor clock via the STM32F103, do I simply hold all pin changes for 7 STM32 cycles (72 host / 10.28 slave)?

The original design had both CPU's @ 3.58 but the coprocessor can run at 10.74Mhz and I would like to max it out.

The shared bus is a standard A(0:23), D(0:7), /RD, /WR, /SEL, /RESET, IRQ

Answer (score 1):

You can run your mcu's clock and coprocessor's clock at whatever frequency you want, it is the bus clock that has to be the same for both of them. 
But watch out, your mcu may not be able to drive the bus at high frequencies if your mcu runs at a low frequncy, see the datasheet for this.

PS: Could you provide a link for the datasheet?